# R: Posthoc comparison for linear mixed effects model

Tags: r, lme4, posthoc

I have run into a problem with the posthoc comparison for my linear mixed effects model. I'll try to explain it with a quickly constructed unperfect example:

Here my example data:

```
Variable<-as.factor(rep(c(1,2,3),5))
Random<-rep(c(1,2,2),5)
Result<-rnorm(15,mean=10,sd=2)

Data<-as.data.frame(cbind(Variable,Random,Result))
```

I actually have several fixed and random effects included in my model, but this is sufficient to illustrate my problem:

```
library(lme4)
LME=lmer(Result~Variable+(1|Random))
summary(LME)
```

Looking at the fixed effects output I only get the significances for the different levels of the variable compared to the Intercept

```
Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   9.5104     1.3685 12.0000   6.949 1.54e-05 ***
Variable2     0.9155     1.9354 12.0000   0.473    0.645    
Variable3     1.7386     1.9354 12.0000   0.898    0.387
```

However, I would now like to compare Variable level 1 with level 2 and Variable level 2 with level 3, so I tried the following:

```
library(multcomp)
summary(glht(LME, linfct=c("Variable2-Variable1=0","Variable3-Variable2=0")))
```

Leaving me with this error:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': multcomp:::chrlinfct2matrix: variable(s) ‘Variable1’ not found
```

If I exclude variable level 1 and only look at the comparison of 2 to 3, the code works fine:

```
summary(glht(LME, linfct=c("Variable3-Variable2=0")))

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Fit: lmer(formula = Result ~ Variable + (1 | Random))

Linear Hypotheses:
                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
Variable3 - Variable2 == 0   0.8231     1.6694   0.493    0.622
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

I can also run the linfct function with Tukey contrasts:

```
summary(glht(LME, linfct= mcp(Variable="Tukey")),test=adjusted("none"))

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts


Fit: lmer(formula = Result ~ Variable + (1 | Random))

Linear Hypotheses:
           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
2 - 1 == 0   0.9155     1.9354   0.473    0.636
3 - 1 == 0   1.7386     1.9354   0.898    0.369
3 - 2 == 0   0.8231     1.6694   0.493    0.622
(Adjusted p values reported -- none method)
```

Seeing that I am not interessted in the comparison of 3 to 1, I would then only use the other 2 p-values and adjust them in a sperate step, but this is not really the solution I am looking for. My data results in more than just the two comparisons shown here, so the option with the Tukey contrasts would leave me with a lot of comparisons I am not really interessted in.

Is there a way to get `Variable1` from `LME`? In the fixed effects it is included as Intercept, replacing `Variable1` with `Intercept` or any combinations I could think of did not do the trick. Or is there generally a better way to achieve the comparisons I am looking for?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've really already got what you want.  In this case, since `Variable=1` is the reference group, it's coefficient is fixed at 0 with a variance of 0.  So, the test of whether `Variable1=Variable2=0` is really just a test of `Variable2=0`.  Likewise with `Variable3`.  You can see this from the fact that the two pieces of code below produce the same output:

```
summary(glht(LME, linfct=c("Variable2=0","Variable3=0", "Variable3-Variable2=0")))

# Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses
# Fit: lmer(formula = Result ~ Variable + (1 | Random))
# Linear Hypotheses:
#                            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
# Variable2 == 0              -0.6524     2.0145  -0.324    0.942
# Variable3 == 0              -2.0845     2.0145  -1.035    0.545
# Variable3 - Variable2 == 0  -1.4321     1.1199  -1.279    0.396
# (Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)

summary(glht(LME, linfct=mcp(Variable="Tukey")))

# Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses
# Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts
# Fit: lmer(formula = Result ~ Variable + (1 | Random))
# Linear Hypotheses:
#            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
# 2 - 1 == 0  -0.6524     2.0145  -0.324    0.942
# 3 - 1 == 0  -2.0845     2.0145  -1.035    0.545
# 3 - 2 == 0  -1.4321     1.1199  -1.279    0.396
# (Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

So, if you only want the adjusted comparisons with the reference, you can do:

```
summary(glht(LME, linfct=c("Variable2=0","Variable3=0")))

# Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses
# Fit: lmer(formula = Result ~ Variable + (1 | Random))
# Linear Hypotheses:
#                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
# Variable2 == 0  -0.6524     2.0145  -0.324    0.889
# Variable3 == 0  -2.0845     2.0145  -1.035    0.404
# (Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```